# Google Geocoding API, HTTP, CSV-data in API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm developing embedded software for a gps-tracker. Until this time I used Google Maps v2 for reverse geocoding (to convert GPS-coordinates to address string). I used http-request and a short-response-form (csv) (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=&output=csv&...). Now, when the support of API v2 is almost over, I try to migrate to v3, but I can't find a csv response-format in http-request settings. The response-size is a critical parameter for the device. How do I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation you're stuck with JSON or XML.

```
A Geocoding API request must be of the following form:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
where output may be either of the following values:
```

- **json** (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
- **xml** indicates output as XML

**Example:** the query should look like this:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=Your+address+here

or

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Your+address+here

where **required** parameter `sensor` indicates you are calling from a location sensor enabled device or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not answer on my question. The size of response is the key point. It's too expensive to receive, store and parse such data sizes. I need just a simple response like a "200,9,"Times Square, 1560 Broadway, New York, NY 10036, USA"". Will API v3 support that format of response?

Comment: No. The according to the documentation the API only supports a JSON or XML response. It sounds like you'll need to write your own web service that will translate the response to something your device can use.

Comment: @user2082893 you should accept this answer. click the "Tick".